# How to change the css style of a button after the mouse release of the :active pseudo class?

Tags: css, button, mouseevent

I would like to ask if there's a way to change the style of an element (like a button) immediately after the :active pseudo-class, that is immediately after the user has released the mouse click on that element, like they do on "Facebook" in the "Sign Up" button ([https://www.facebook.com/](https://www.facebook.com) just try to click on it and then when you release the mouse you'll see the button become white in the background. 
Is it possible with css or should I use JQuery? How can I do that?

Comment: As far as I know, that can't be achieved with css pseudo-classes. You'll most likely have to change the color in the onclick event with JavaScript

Comment: use the checkbox trick and throw the actual box off screen or lower in the z-index.

Comment: You will most probably need to target the `on('mouseup', callback)` event

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <title></title>
    <style  type="text/css">
        div{
            width:100px;
        }
        a:link{
            color:blue;
        }
        a:visited{
            color:yellow;
        }
        a:hover{
            color:green;
        }       
        a:active{
            color:red;
        }
        a:link > div{
            background-color:yellow;
        }
        a:visited > div{
            background-color:green;
        }
        a:hover > div{
            background-color:red;
        }       
        a:active > div{
            background-color:blue;
        }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href=""><div>Click</div></a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Is this what you meant?

Comment: No, it isn't. Your link becomes blue when you click on it but when you release the mouse button the links becomes green again. I would like to turn the link background, for example to purple after you release the mouse click, and after some time become again green, maybe should I use a Javascript event onclick? But how can I do that?

Comment: I'll show you tomorrow. Today I'll enjoy some family time. I wish you a happy new year!

Comment: Thanks! Happy New Year to you too! I'll wait.